# .net core (Razor). partial view post with jquery method to controller. the HttpContext session keys empty

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I  have partial view which refresh itself  every several seconds.
the view calling post method in the partial view controller.
on post, i need to get several values which stored in session data.
but it seems that the HttpRequest getting different HttpContext/Session and doesnt have the keys.

any solution for that?
thank you.

Comment: Hi, have you added the config to force using session inside .NET Core? Are you using Cookie for this?

Comment: hi @tartarismo i'm using session session not cookies. can u point for the config u mentioned?

Comment: Are you using absolute or relative path when calling the POST request?

Comment: you didn't store the session value correctly / session already expired / the same session? [related document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#session-state).

Comment: `[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SetSession()
    {
        //Set value in Session object.
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Name", "Mudassar Khan");
 
        //Get SessionID inside Controller.
        TempData["SessionID"] = HttpContext.Session.Id;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }` code like this may be able to get session id , and you can check if you had different sessionid.